# Serializing, storing, and deserializing WS objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm using the NodeJS ws library to build an app. Currently I am using an object to store instances of users' websocket connections with a unique user ID as the key.
Pseudo-code:

`let userWebSockets = {
   'user-guid-here': WSConnection

 };`

This works fine and when I need to target a specific user to send a message back to I can grab their connection from the `userWebSockets` object thusly `let ws = userWebSockets['user-guid-here']`.

The problem is, if I cluster Node processes on the box I am running, fork a master process with the cluster module, or cluster the boxes, then there is no guarantee that the same `userWebSockets` object will be in memory, and when I try to look up a user's connection based on their unique identifier, I risk getting `undefined` as the return value from the lookup.

My first inclination was to use some remote k => v store like Redis to handle maintaining the dictionary, however I realized in my implementation attempt that Redis obviously isn't going to store a Javascript object and the best I could do with such a technology was serialize the object in a way that it could later be reconstituted/deserialized. I tried using Crockford's cycle.js from the following repository: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js This was unsuccessful as I found that prototype methods of the object I was trying to bring back to life were not preserved (`ws.send()` in this case, for example).

My current workaround is to use nginx to balance to an upstream pool of instances and use the ip_hash directive to make the user ip => instance sticky, however I'm not satisfied with this solution.

Has anybody had any luck with what I'm trying to do here? I'm also open to re-architecting the app if there is a better or more idiomatic way to handle user => ws connection associations.

Comment: Hi, I am facing similar problem. Did you find some solution?

Comment: I'm afraid not @AbdulBasit - I stuck with the solution of making user ip => instance sticky for that project. Let me know if you find something more elegant, I would be excited to hear!